# Trying to populate a dropdown menu in codeigniter with mysql data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, drop-down-menu, codeigniter-form-helper

Im trying to populate a dropdown box on a registraton form in code igniter but i have had not luck below are snippets from my contorller, model, and view. Base is the drop down field.

Model

```
 function get_airports()
    {
        $this->db->select('airport_code, airport_name');
        $this->db->order_by('airport_code', "asc");
        $query = $this->db->get('airports');
    if($query){
        $query = $query->result_array();
        return $query;
    }
    }

    }return $data
    }
    function create_member()
    {
        $new_member_insert_data = array('first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
            'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'), 
            'email_address'=> $this->input->post('email_address'),
            'username'=> $this->input->post('username'),
            'password'=> md5($this->input->post('password')),
            'birthdate'=> $this->input->post('birthdate'),
            'base'=> $this->input->post('base')
        );
        $insert = $this->db->insert('membership', $new_member_insert_data);
        return $insert;
    }

} ?>
```

View

```
    $airports = $this->get_airports(true,'Please Select');
$selected = set_my_defaults('airport',$default);

echo form_dropdown('base', set_value('base', $airports, $selected, 'class="dropdown_style"'));
```

View 2 Bases i made this a sperate view and included it in the main registration form

```
<select>
<?php 
    foreach($myDropdown as $dd)
        echo "<option value='". $dd['your_field'] ."'>". $dd['your_field'] ."</option>";
?>
</select>
```

controller

```
function getairport(){
$query = $this->membership_model->get_airports();
if($query)
{
    $data['main_content'] = 'base';
    $this->load->view('base', $data);
}
}
        function create_member()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        //fieldname,  error messaage, validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'Name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_address', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[4]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2', 'Password Confirmation', 'trim|required|matches[password]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('birthdate', 'Birthdate', 'trim|required|');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('base', 'Base', 'trim|required');

        if($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE)
        {
```

Answer (score 0):

Your format should be like this:

```
$options = array(
                  'small'  => 'Small Shirt',
                  'med'    => 'Medium Shirt',
                  'large'   => 'Large Shirt',
                  'xlarge' => 'Extra Large Shirt',
                );

$shirts_on_sale = array('small', 'large');

echo form_dropdown('shirts', $options, 'large');
```

this would produce:

```
<select name="shirts">
    <option value="small">Small Shirt</option>
    <option value="med">Medium Shirt</option>
    <option value="large" selected="selected">Large Shirt</option>
    <option value="xlarge">Extra Large Shirt</option>
</select>
```

REFER  **[HERE](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)**

---

**UPDATE**

you could also try this if you want

**MODEL**

```
$this->db->select('airport_code, airport_name');
$this->db->order_by('airport_code', "asc");
$query = $this->db->get('airports');
if($query)
{
    $query = $query->result_array();
    return $query;
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$query = $this->your_model->your_method();
if($query)
{
    $data['myDropdown'] = $query;
    $this->load->view('your_view', $data);
}
```

**VIEW** - **YOUR DROPDOWN PROBLEM**

```
<select>
<?php 
    foreach($myDropdown as $dd)
        echo "<option value='". $dd['your_field'] ."'>". $dd['your_field'] ."</option>";
?>
</select>
```

Comment: My data is not written in the code, it comes from a sql database

Comment: can you show what your `$airports` look like? `print_r($airports)`

Comment: when i try that i get this Call to undefined method CI_Loader::get_airports() on line 9

line 9
$airports = $this->get_airports(true,'Please Select');

Comment: should that just be `$this->db->get('airports');` ?

Comment: I put that in the view file where the old line 9 was and it returned this. CI_DB_mysql_result Object ( [conn_id] => Resource id #29 [result_id] => Resource id #36 [result_array] => Array ( ) [result_object] => Array ( ) [custom_result_object] => Array ( ) [current_row] => 0 [num_rows] => 5 [row_data] => )

Comment: im using the form helper in Codeigniter is your code in the view section going to affect that?

Comment: It looks like your result array is empty. Check your dastabase/query.

Comment: its kinda complicated if you use `form_dropdown` from the kind of data return from `->result_array` the array return from `result_array` is **multidimensional** and `form_dropdown` accepts a simple array see the sample.

Comment: @KobusMyburgh no, It has, see `[num_rows]=>5` ? the result was like that because maybe he hadn't made the `->result_array`

Comment: Alright thanks, I'll mess around with it and see if i can get it to work.

Comment: When i run it with the orginal above code i get this It runs, when i try to load the drop down i get this Severity: Warning Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() Filename: helpers/form_helper.php Line Number: 331

Comment: @Þaw alright the code is updated and i still get the same error

Comment: you just copied my code? you havent replaced it with your real variables? Dont copy the exact code replace it with your code if where it can be applied

Comment: @Þaw I thought i had, which variables need to be changed?

Comment: @user1537210 the one in the **VIEW** you just copied the `$dd['your_field']` it was just a representation

Comment: @Þaw like this
<select>
<?php 
    foreach($query as $q)
        echo "<option value='". $q['airport_code'] ."'>". $q['airport_name'] ."</option>";
?>
</select>

Comment: Yes. Try it and tell me what you get

Comment: @Þaw Nothing its not populateing the drop down