# Form Helper Drop Down Menu

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-form-helper

Is there a way to create a MySQL linked dropdown menu using the form helper in CodeIgniter? I tried to do it but I cannot seem to get it to work.

**Model**

```
function get_airports()
    {
        $this->db->select('airport_code, airport_name');
        $this->db->order_by('airport_code', "asc");
        $query = $this->db->get('airports');
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
        $data{$row['airport_code']} = $row['status'];
    }

    }return $data;
    }
    function create_member()
    {
        $new_member_insert_data = array('first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
            'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'), 
            'email_address'=> $this->input->post('email_address'),
            'username'=> $this->input->post('username'),
            'password'=> md5($this->input->post('password'))
            'birthdate'=> $this->input->post('birthdate'),
            'base'=> $this->input->post('base')
        );
        $insert = $this->db->insert('membership', $new_member_insert_data);
        return $insert;
    }

} ?>
```

View

```
echo form_dropdown('base', set_value('base', 'Select a Base'));
```

Controller

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('base', 'Base', 'trim|required');
```

Comment: Just found [this using a search engine](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html) - looks like `form_dropdown` is what you need. Can we see your code? (If you could _always_ supply code here when asking questions, that is most helpful, and saves people asking).

Comment: Eh? You asked this question [a week ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977417/trying-to-populate-a-dropdown-menu-in-codeigniter-with-mysql-data).

Comment: Yes i did but no one really helped so i asked again.

Comment: My recommendation would be to let this question close, and add a comment under your existing question - I think that is sufficient to pop it to the front page. From what I can tell, the help from Þaw is excellent, incidentally.

Comment: Too many syntax errors here, `'password'=> md5($this->input->post('password'))` needs a comma, you have unexpected braces everywhere.

Comment: I was going to clean up the code for this question, but as @DaveChen says, there are too many errors. I doubt this code even works.

Comment: What is this? `$data{$row['airport_code']}` Have you accurately copied this code from your editor? You should try to get it running first, so then at least you have some run-time errors to respond to.

Comment: It runs, when i try to load the drop down i get this Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: helpers/form_helper.php

Line Number: 331

Comment: You need to use @halfer to notify me of updates, incidentally. I see that someone is helping you on your duplicate post, so work with them to resolve this please (two sources of help will just duplicate each other here).

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make your dropdown like this:

```
<?PHP 
                $options    =   $this->db->query('Select province_id as value, province as display FROM ndi_provinces')->result();
                $prov_options = array(''=>'Select');
                foreach($options as $option){
                    $prov_options[$option->value] = $option->display;
                }
                $prov_optionAtt = "id='province_id'  readonly='readonly'";
                echo form_dropdown('province_id',$prov_options, isset($_POST['province_id'])?$_POST['province_id']:$participant->province_id, $prov_optionAtt);
            ?><span class="required">*</span>
```

and another better way is to make your dropdown options in your controller
and send it as a variable to view